# Qt style sheet properties for toolbox buttons

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I want to give some color to the area where they are toolbox buttons with icons (light grey on picture). Please help in determining what is a parameter style sheet?

[image: www.app4tablet.com/marek/toolbar_color.png]

Comment: What object are those toolbox buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to change the background color of the toolbar area.

Suppose I have a mainwindow with a toolbar called `mainToolBar`. Here is what I did :

```
ui->mainToolBar->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background : red; } QToolButton { background : green; }");
```

The first part of the stylesheet will change the background color of the toolbar where there is no toolbuttons.

The second part of the stylesheet will change the background color of the toolbuttons.

Note : I tested the code snippet above on Windows, I suppose it should work on a Mac too, but I cannot guarantee.

Comment: works great on windows, on mac and linux no work.  http://www.app4tablet.com/marek/mac-win-linux.png